# Dev Tools shows endless network loop for Blazor deployed application

Tags: c#, debugging, blazor, webassembly

I am working on a blazor application.  When I debug locally, I have no issues.

However, when I deploy it to IIS (locally or on a server), the network tab of dev tools in Chrome shows a endless loop.

local screenshot:
[image]

deployed in IIS screenshot (thousands of requests and growing):

[image]

**My question(s):** how can I figure out where this call is coming from?  Can I turn of the encoding or something?

Comment: My guess would be that you have a race condition going on in your rendering, such that HasChanged keeps getting called (maybe in OnAfterAsync).

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 you are right!.  My OnAfterRender was calling a method which triggered a StateHasChanged..  as to why it only looped when deployed, I have no idea.

Comment: Yeah, that's a classic "race condition" with threaded systems: things finish so fast on your dev system that you won't notice what will happen when the wrong thread finishes first.

Comment: Is this a problem? Do I have to solve this or I can leave it as it is? I am also having this endless loop problem what I have to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added logging to my razor page events, and found the loop.

The OnAfterRenderAsync called another method which included a StateHasChanged.  This resulted in an endless loop.

Reading about the component lifecycles here:
https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/

We can see OnAfterRenderAsync fires any time the state changes.  So I had to basically remove any logic from OnAfterRenderAsync that would cause the state of the component to change.

Comment: Remember to mark your answer as the correct one, so people can see the problem was solved.  I'm guessing very many people have done something like this in Blazor.

Comment: Is this a problem? Do I have to solve this or I can leave it as it is? I am also having this endless loop problem what I have to do ?

Comment: Yes Arjun, it is a problem.  I will update my answer to be more descriptive on what the solution was.